Conversion of the projection step between jos stams stable fluid and realtime fluid paper
I am curious about fluid dynamics and read two papers from Jos Stam. While studying them I encountered something I couldnt explain: 
I cant figure out how the evolution of stams projection step between the two papers is mathmatically possible. Why is it allowed, that the $h^2$ is absent in the lowest equation?
Here are the equations from stams stable fluid paper (chapter 2 eq. 4).
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&& \nabla^2 p &= \nabla\vec{w}_3\\
&&\Leftrightarrow \frac{p_{i+1,j}+p_{i-1,j}+p_{i,j+1}+p_{i,j-1}-4p_{i,j}}{h^2}&=\frac{\vec{w}_{i+1,j\,x}^3-\vec{w}_{i-1,j\,x}^3}{2h}+\frac{\vec{w}_{i,j+1\,y}^3-\vec{w}_{i,j-1\,y}^3}{2h}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Here are the equations from stams paper Real-Time Fluid Dynamics for Games  (page 10).
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&& p_{i,j} &= \frac{-\nabla \vec{w}^3 + p_{i-1,j}+p_{i+1,j}+p_{i,j-1}+p_{i,j+1}}{4}\\
&& \Leftrightarrow p_{i+1,j}+p_{i-1,j}+p_{i,j+1}+p_{i,j-1}-4p_{i,j}&=\nabla\vec{w}^3 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

He set $h=1$ - it's not that uncommon for people to do this.

In the code of Real-Time Fluid Dynamics for Games on page 10 is $h$ set to $1.0/N$,  with N beeing the width of the velocity field (number of vectors in x and y direction). Or is it allowed for some reason to use another step size for the pressure grid than the velocity grid has?

$h=1/N$ just means you pretend the grid is embedded in an interval of size $1$. If you pretend the grid is embedded in an interval of size $N$ then $h=1$.

I understand that if you pretend the grid is $N$ wide $h$ would be $1$. But the text clearly says: "We also assume that the physical length of each side of the grid is one so that the
grid spacing is given by $h=1/N$" (page 4 top).
So we have a grid that is $1$ wide and we have more than one vector so $h=1/N$ has to be something smaller than $1$.

I checked the article. Indeed, he doesn't set $h=1$. I wrote an answer to explain what's going on. I made that mistake because what you wrote is not what he had in code, notably you wrote $-\nabla \cdot \vec{w}$, but it's really $-h\nabla \cdot \vec{w}$. Granted, the naming in the code is not ideal, as he named the variable div to represent $-h\nabla \cdot \vec{w}$.

I went to the project part in the code of the article "Real-Time Fluid Dynamics for Games" that you linked. You have:
p[IX(i,j)] = (div[IX(i,j)]+p[IX(i-1,j)]+p[IX(i+1,j)]+   p[IX(i,j-1)]+p[IX(i,j+1)])/4;

where div is:
div[IX(i,j)] = -0.5*h*(u[IX(i+1,j)]-u[IX(i-1,j)]+  v[IX(i,j+1)]-v[IX(i,j-1)]);

Now consider:
\begin{align}
\Delta p &= \nabla \cdot \begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \end{bmatrix} \\
\frac{p_{i+1,j} +p_{i-1,j}+p_{i,j+1}+p_{i,j-1}-4p_{i,j}}{h^2} &= \frac{u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j}}{2h} + \frac{v_{i,j+1}-v_{i,j-1}}{2h} \\
p_{i+1,j} +p_{i-1,j}+p_{i,j+1}+p_{i,j-1}-4p_{i,j} &= \frac{h}{2}(u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j}) + \frac{h}{2}(v_{i,j+1}-v_{i,j-1})
\end{align}
Keeping $p_{i,j}$ on one side we get:
\begin{equation}
p_{i,j} = \frac{-\frac{h}{2}(u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j}+v_{i,j+1}-v_{i,j-1}) + p_{i+1,j} +p_{i-1,j}+p_{i,j+1}+p_{i,j-1}}{4} .
\end{equation}
But this is precisely what you see in the code.
Edit:
Assume that $h_x\ne h_y$. For example if you have a rectangular grid or you want the steps to be different along $x$ and $y$ you would choose a different number of samples along each direction $(N_x\ne N_y)$ and you get: $1/N_x = h_x \ne h_y = 1/N_y$.
Going back to the original expression:
\begin{align}
\partial_{xx} p + \partial_{yy} p = \Delta p &= \nabla \cdot \begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \end{bmatrix} = \partial_x u + \partial_y v \\
\frac{p_{i+1,j}-2p_{i,j}+p_{i-1,j}}{h_x^2} + 
\frac{p_{i,j+1}-2p_{i,j}+p_{i,j-1}}{h_y^2} &= 
\frac{u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j}}{2h_x} + \frac{v_{i,j+1}-v_{i,j-1}}{2h_y} \\
h_y^2(p_{i+1,j}-2p_{i,j}+p_{i-1,j}) + h_x^2(p_{i,j+1}-2p_{i,j}+p_{i,j-1}) &= \frac{h_xh_y^2}{2}(u_{i+1}-u_{i-1}) + \frac{h_x^2h_y}{2}(v_{i,j+1}-v_{i,j-1})
\end{align}
Thus ultimately you get:
\begin{equation}
p_{i,j} = \frac{h_y^2}{2(h_x^2+h_y^2)}(p_{i+1,j}+p_{i-1,j}) 
+ \frac{h_x^2}{2(h_x^2+h_y^2)}(p_{i,j+1}+p_{i,j-1}) 
- \frac{h_xh_y^2}{4(h_x^2+h_y^2)}(u_{i+1}-u_{i-1}) - \frac{h_x^2h_y}{4(h_x^2+h_y^2)}(v_{i,j+1}-v_{i,j-1})
\end{equation}

Thank you so much! I just realized my careless mistake: I converted $0.5h$ the whole time to $\frac{1}{2h}$ istead of $\frac{h}{2}$. My god thanks for your patience and for your help! It makes so much sense now!

@JanFlemming Note that if $h_x\ne h_y$ you need a modified version of the update rule - I added it to my answer.
